# How do I get the desired result when formatting a string in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, formatting

Right now I'm in the proces of refactoring and am looking for a clean solution for some repetitive code. I basically have a class where a question is determined and as an output I get: the question as a string, a randomised array of answers and the correct answer.

There are different types of questions (integer addition/subtraction, decimal multiplication, etc.) With the integers everything goes fine, but when I go to decimal multiplication for some reason the correct answer only gives "." instead of let's say "0.00035".

I format the array as follows:

```
ansArray =[String(format:"%.5f",a+e), String(format:"%.5f",a+e+0.01), String(format:"%.5f",a+e+0.09), String(format:"%.5f",a+e-0.1), String(format:"%.5f",a+e+0.1)]
```

and the answer:

```
answer = String(format:"%.5",a+e)
```

EDIT: missing **f**

where a and e are randomised numbers of type Double. If I don't use any formatting on the answer string, I do get the a+e value instead of "."
I think I'm missing something here and just cannot get it to work.

Also, doing the formatting like this is repetitive, if there a clean way to format the entire array without doing the individual strings? ( I can write a function for it must there must be something more elegant than that right?)

Comment: There is no format specified in `"%.5"` ...

Comment: `let ansArray = [a+e, a+e+0.01, a+e+0.09,a+e-0.1,a+e+0.1].map{String(format:"%.5f", $0)}`

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for your help with formatting the array, this works perfectly.